# Get Gradle test results after hung test

Tags: junit, gradle

In our software, we have a few JUnit tests that occasionally hang during execution due to race conditions in the tests.  When one of these hangs occurred last night, I just killed the forked Java process that was running the test.  The tests continued running as expected until the build completed.

After the build, I got an error message (I was running with --continue) about having killed Gradle Test Executor xxx.  When I went to look at the test results, I discovered that the HTML test report wasn't there, and neither were the XML test result files.

From this I have two questions:  How can I generate the test reports without rerunning all of the tests (they take a night to run)?  How can I gracefully handle a hung test without effecting the build output?

Comment: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests ? However, the *real* problem is indeterministic tests - having interference-sensitive tests can be often a sign of badly written code.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't anything we can do about the tests other than adding the timeout.  Adding the timeout is a little difficult since the test report is missing, preventing us from identifying the hanging test.  The non-determinism is due to them being tests for a set of distributed services that are performing time-based events.  We've made attempts in the past at fixing the timing issues, but, while we've managed to improve the reliability of the tests, we have yet to come up with a cure-all that doesn't involve deep changes to the product being tested.